# How can I sort text data by timestamp in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, sorting, date, awk

So, I have some data that looks like this:

```
19/10/2020 05:57:08.200, 362173.64, 4498564.26, 10.000, 10.000,   0.000, 0, 3.2,  
19/10/2020 05:57:08.270, 362173.64, 4498564.38, 10.000, 10.000,   0.000, 0, 3.2,  
19/10/2020 05:57:08.340, 362173.64, 4498564.49, 10.000, 10.000,   0.000, 0, 3.2,  
19/10/2020 05:57:08.410, 362173.64, 4498564.61, 10.000, 10.000,   0.000, 0, 3.7,  
19/10/2020 05:57:08.470, 362173.64, 4498564.72, 10.000, 10.000,   0.000, 0, 2.8,
```

I need to sort the data by time stamp. Under linux, I would run this data through awk to pick apart the date and time to look like this:

```
2020 05 10 19 57 08.200  362173.64  4498564.26  10.000  10.000    0.000  0  3.2  
2020 05 10 19 57 08.270  362173.64  4498564.38  10.000  10.000    0.000  0  3.2  
2020 05 10 19 57 08.340  362173.64  4498564.49  10.000  10.000    0.000  0  3.2
```

Using a command like this:

```
awk -F'[/:,]' '{print $3,$2,$1,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14}'
```

Then run that through sort and back through awk to put the columns back in the correct order.

```
awk -F'[/:,]' '{print $3,$2,$1,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14}' | sort | 
awk -F' ' '{print $3"/"$2"/"$1,$4":"$5":"$6","$7","$8","$9","$10","$11","$12","$13","$14}'
```

Is there a better way to do this in powershell, or at least a way to do the same thing? I have a powershell script that very clumsily does something similar, but somewhere in the process I lose the newlines...

```
$nav = (gc $navfile | %{$_ -replace ", ",","} | %{$_ -replace "  ",""} | %{"$($_.Split('[/,:]')[2,1,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14])"} | sort-object | %{"$($_.Split(' ')[2,1,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14])"} )  

[regex]$sorted = " "


$one = $sorted.replace($nav, "/", 2)  
$two = $sorted.replace($one, "!", 1)  
$three = $sorted.replace($two, ":", 2)  
$four = $three | %{$_ -replace " ",","}  
$five = $four | %{$_ -replace "!"," "}  
$six = $five | %{$_ -replace ",,","`n"}  
echo $six
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "powershell" is a windows thing, right? And if you're on Windows then you're using GNU awk, and GNU awk comes with it's own `sort` functionality so - why not just do it all in 1 call to awk? If you [edit] your question to show the expected output then we can help you - I tried running the `awk | sort | awk` pipeline you provided on the data you posted but the output didn't make sense so I assume that script or the sample input isn't actually correct.  Isn't your posted sample input already sorted by timestamp? If so, that's not useful to test a sorting function.

Comment: @EdMorton powershell is a general shell that's available for [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7.1) and [macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-macos?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: I'm making a portable tool for others to use under windows, which is why I'm working in powershell. The data in the example happens to be sorted, but the full data is not. I may have missed something in explaining the awk code, but I have a functioning script under linux.

Comment: When asking a question it's important to show a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (so if your problem is how to sort data, provide unsorted data for the sample input and the same data sorted for the expected output) along with actual code that does what you say with the example you provide. Otherwise it's like asking your mechanic to help get your car started when you actually have a horse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell, you can use [the `Sort-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) - and you don't need to modify the source file, at all:

```
Get-Content $navfile |Sort-Object {
  [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Substring(0, 23), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff', $null)
}
```

The `$_.Substring(0, 23)` expression will extract the first 23 characters, ie. `19/10/2020 05:57:08.200`. The `[datetime]::ParseExact()` call then parses the resulting string as a timestamp with the format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff`, and the resulting `[datetime]` value is then used as the sorting key.

Answer (score 1):

If your input really was unsorted:

```
$ cat file
21/10/2020 05:57:08.470, 362173.64, 4498564.72, 10.000, 10.000,   0.000, 0, 2.8,
19/10/2020 05:57:08.340, 362173.64, 4498564.49, 10.000, 10.000,   0.000, 0, 3.2,
08/10/2020 05:57:08.270, 362173.64, 4498564.38, 10.000, 10.000,   0.000, 0, 3.2,
19/10/2020 05:57:08.410, 362173.64, 4498564.61, 10.000, 10.000,   0.000, 0, 3.7,
19/10/2020 05:57:08.200, 362173.64, 4498564.26, 10.000, 10.000,   0.000, 0, 3.2,
```

here's how you could sort it by date+time just using GNU awk:

```
$ awk -F'[/ ]' '
    { rec[$3 $2 $1 $4] = $0 }
    END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"; for (ts in rec) print rec[ts] }
' file
08/10/2020 05:57:08.270, 362173.64, 4498564.38, 10.000, 10.000,   0.000, 0, 3.2,
19/10/2020 05:57:08.200, 362173.64, 4498564.26, 10.000, 10.000,   0.000, 0, 3.2,
19/10/2020 05:57:08.340, 362173.64, 4498564.49, 10.000, 10.000,   0.000, 0, 3.2,
19/10/2020 05:57:08.410, 362173.64, 4498564.61, 10.000, 10.000,   0.000, 0, 3.7,
21/10/2020 05:57:08.470, 362173.64, 4498564.72, 10.000, 10.000,   0.000, 0, 2.8,
```

Obviously that's being run on Unix - apply Windows magic quoting rules as/if appropriate (or just save the script in a file and run it as `awk -f script file`).

Comment: I don't understand what your awk code is doing, but when I run it, the output is unsorted.

Comment: @SamAlleman it's just creating an array of records (each line of input being a record) indexed by the date+time values then printing  the contents of that array in the order of it's indices, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal. If the output you get isn't sorted then either you aren't using GNU awk or you're using a **very** old version of it that doesn't support `sorted_in` or your real input doesn't look like the example you provided. Add some print statements throughout it to dump values used if it's not obvious.

Comment: Ah, I was using mawk, not gnu awk. Let me give that another try. Thanks!

Comment: Gnu awk fixed it, but it's about half the speed of what I was doing before. I guess mawk doesn't support "sorted_in"...

Comment: Right, mawk is traditionally a minimal-featured awk designed for speed of execution whereas gawk is feature-rich designed for enhanced functionality. Also, `sort` is a utility designed specifically to sort data so you should expect it to be able to do so faster than some other tool that just does sorting as an extra bit of functionality. Having said that - half the speed sounds like a lot, I wonder if the script you're running is just doing exactly what I show or other things too that might be slowing it down, and I wonder if you did 3rd-run timing or if you're experiencing cache-ing impact.

Comment: Looking at the 2 mawk scripts plus the `sort` in your question, I'm having a **really** hard time believing that running 1 gawk script takes twice as long because those scripts are doing field splitting twice and string concatenation as well as I/O. When doing any timing comparisons, make sure to run each script 3 times and take the 3rd timing output for each so the results aren't impacted by cache-ing.

Comment: I'm running the scripts on a 25Mb file under WSL 2, if that makes any difference. I'm not using the time command to get run times, but actually checking the time/date in the script before and after each run.

Comment: @SamAlleman no, that doesn't make any difference. Whatever you're doing you should run it 3 times per tool and just take the 3rd value to get values you can compare.

Comment: I tried to send you the results via chat yesterday. For three runs of mawk | sort | mawk, the times were 17s, 15s, and 16s. For three runs of gawk, the times were 30s, 29s, 29s. This was done consecutively and on the same data set.

Comment: OK, sounds like gawk alone is slower, thanks for following up.

Comment: I have no idea why this would be. I do like the code that you provided and I plan to pick it apart and learn from it. It's certainly vastly more elegant than my solution.

Comment: I already told you why it could be - `mawk` is designed to manipulate text faster than `gawk` and `sort` is designed to sort faster than `gawk`, see [my earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65778222/how-can-i-sort-text-data-by-timestamp-in-powershell/65778557?noredirect=1#comment116304568_65778557). I just didn't expect there to be such a big difference but I guess I was wrong.